# Internet problems with Netgear WNA3100

Tags: internet

Every time I try to connect to my Internet using a Netgear WNA3100 adapter, once I enter in the password it says `WPA is incompatible with static WEP keys`. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: The recommended wireless encryption settings (at your router) are: WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Check and correct that accordingly before anything else.

Comment: i switched it to WPA2-PSK (AES) and i entered the password correctly and its still saying the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Enter your wireless router's administration web page by using your web browser and going to http://192.168.0.1 (or http://192.168.1.1).

Use your administrator's login name and password to log in. Find the wireless security tab, and look for something that indicates that enryption is currently set to WEP. Change this setting to **WPA2**, or **WPA2-AES**.

There may also be a setting in the same area that indicates TKIP or AES. Make sure it's set to **AES**.

There's also a password field that you need to make sure is known to you. Now you should be able to connect using your Netgear wireless adapter.

Comment: i switched it to WPA2-PSK (AES) and i entered the password correctly and its still saying the same thing

Comment: How have you installed the drivers? With *ndiswrapper*? I so, I'm fraid that sooner or later, something of the sort would happen. The "wrapper" is  a 'hack' to use old WinXP drivers because there are no others for Linux. Consider replacing it with a better, newer, faster, more stable and with native support dongle. You can find them for as little as $8 or even less. With some luck you can sell the Netgear on eBay for the same price.

Comment: So i have to get a new adapter?

Comment: When you changed the router's settings, you **saved** the settings, yes? Now go to your network menu and choose Edit Connections. Find the wireless profile named after your wireless network name. Go to the wi-fi security tab, and make sure it says WPA2 there also. Retype the password also. Then try again.  Also, tell us what driver that you're using. Cheers, Al

Comment: One more thing to try. Go back to your router's security tab, and change security from WPA2-PSK to none. Do the same in your network config on your computer. Then try again. If it works, we'll try the next step. Cheers, Al